# Building a table from for loop values in QGIS

Tags: raster, pyqgis, volume

I am calculating the volume of a few lakes at 1 cm intervals. In QGIS I am using the raster surface volume tool and I am trying to iterate the process in a for loop so that I don't have to manually adjust the base level a couple of hundred times.

The problem I am running into is the output overwrites the previous output and I end up with a single value (whatever value was last in the list of values). Is there a way to write each output onto a new line in the csv?

my code:

```
from qgis import processing
'lake_level'= (169.50,169.49)
processing.run("qgis:rastersurfacevolume",{'INPUT':'/mydata.TIF',
    'BAND': 1,
    'LEVEL': lake_level,
    'METHOD': 1,
    'OUTPUT_TABLE': '/MY_TABLE.CSV',
     })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
from qgis import processing
with open('/MY_TABLE.CSV','w+') as summary_csv:
   for level in range(169.49,170.00,0.01):
       'lake_level'= (level+0.01,level)
       processing.run("qgis:rastersurfacevolume",{'INPUT':'/mydata.TIF',
        'BAND': 1,
        'LEVEL': lake_level,
        'METHOD': 1,
        'OUTPUT_TABLE': '/_TEMP.CSV',
        })
        with open('/_TEMP.CSV') as f:
           content = f.read().splitlines()
        summary_csv.write("{},{}".format(level,content[-1]))
```

This loops on `level`, repeatedly processes into a temp file named `/_TEMP.CSV` , and postprocesses the last lines of the results onto the end of a summary file named `/MY_TABLE.CSV`.

Comment: This was a good way to deal with the range. QGIS wouldn't read the float value before. Iterating with Range is productive.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it with the geoprocess, I think you're going to have to cut your dem into smaller layers that cover each pond. Then you can put all the dem's in a list and create a cycle.

The process requires a path as a string that you can alter sequentially, so that each loop has a .csv file.

**Another option is to program the process**

With PyQGIS,using QgsRaterLayer Blocks, for each loop, or generate a model, I will explain you how to do it manually with the raster calculator:

Let's say we have a resolution dem (10x10 pixel size), block1, is the first block. We are interested in volume below 280.

1- for each block create a raster that assigns the elevation values to the pixels with a dimension lower than the base dimension, and value 280 to the rest. In the raster would be like this:

```
lake = (block1@1 < 280) * block1@1 + (block@1 > 280) * 280
```

2- we calculate the depths, i.e. the distance from the 280 level to the bottom. To do this, we simply subtract 280

```
depth = 280 - lake
```

3.- Then add up the depths, for this purpose Process Menu > Process Toolbox, in the Panel look for the label Raster> Raster Layer Statistics, look for the result of the sum, say for example it gives 3372.4891967773438

4.- Calculate the volume 3372.4891967773438*100 m2= 337248,9196777 m3